# Custom Object IN NSSet NSPredicate with SQL

Tags: sql, debugging, core-data, nspredicate, nsset

A NSManagedObject has a property as Transformable which I use to store a NSMutableOrderedSet.

This set contains custom objects (not subclasses of NSManagedObject) which implement NSCoding and override the isEqual: and hash methods.

I have a NSPredicate which checks if this set contains a passed object.

The predicate is basically this one:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN %K", theObjectToCheck, @"propertyNameForTheSet"];
```

It works with the database in memory but with SQL it fires a BAD ACCESS error.

I have all diagnostics enabled.

The sql debug is something like:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t0.Z_PK) FROM ZIMPLEMENTED_ABSTRACT_ENTITY_NAME t0 WHERE ( NSCoreDataStringSearch( t0.ZPROPERTYNAMEFORTHESET1, ?, 0, 0) AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?) 
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = theObjectToCheckAsString(not-hash)
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = 6
```

The stack trace is:

```
0   ???                                 0x00000001eee4d8dc 0x0 + 8302942428,
1   Spatch                              0x00000001020d5ee0 main + 0, 
2   CoreData                            0x000000010386ee26 _NSCoreDataStringSearch + 246,
3   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x0000000107337384 sqlite3VdbeExec + 16100,
4   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x000000010728e4ff sqlite3_step + 527,
5   CoreData                            0x0000000103820070 _execute + 112,
6   CoreData                            0x000000010381fd0b -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 1835,
7   CoreData                            0x0000000103879b18 -[NSSQLChannel selectCountWithFetchRequest:] + 168,
8   CoreData                            0x00000001038796b5 -[NSSQLCore countForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 405,
9   CoreData                            0x0000000103825f01 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 513,
10  CoreData                            0x00000001038fb4f3 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3331,
11  CoreData                            0x00000001039037ee gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 190,
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001056b17f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8,
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105698774 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365,
14  CoreData                            0x00000001038f63d5 _perform + 197,
15  CoreData                            0x0000000103825ac8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504,
16  CoreData                            0x0000000103878c80 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _countWithNoChangesForRequest:error:] + 288,
17  CoreData                            0x000000010387868b -[NSManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:error:] + 331,
```

It seems there are similarities with: http://markmail.org/message/7cuuamyc4gcid5bb#query:+page:1+mid:h2t4o4moib3emltb+state:results
[image]

Sample project can be checked here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2935618/CustomObjectsInCoreData.zip

Any ideas how I could get to the bottom of this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm 99% sure this isn't possible, and if it was the performance would be pretty horrible.

Is there any reason why you can't make a proper core data entity and appropriate relationship for the objects in your ordered set?

Comment: yep, if the custom object extends nsmanagedobject, and is connected through a relationship, I can search for it. A bit surprised I can't search for a string in an attribute which contains a set of strings though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to search for objects in NSPredicate with SQL if these are not entities and are not connected through an explicit relationship in the core data model.